# Android Wear: save file locally

Tags: file, exception, save, wear-os, java-io

it is possible to saving file in a wearable?
i try the same procedure i use on phone but java.io send me an Exception.

File directory = null;

```
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String path = sd.getAbsolutePath();

    directory = new File(path, dirName);

    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = null;
    String extension = ".arff";
    String completeName = fileName + extension;

    try {
        file = new File(directory, completeName);
        if(!file.isFile())
            file.createNewFile();
        else {

            String[] parts = fileName.split("_");
            String baseName = parts[0];
            String num = parts[1];
            int i = Integer.parseInt(num);
            do{

                String newFileName = baseName+"_"+(i+1)+extension;
                file = new File(directory, newFileName);
                i++;

            } while(file.isFile());

            file.createNewFile();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "Exception while creating file:" + e.toString());
    }
```

Must i write on internal or external storage? Is it possible to retrieve this file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you example to store image and get it back.

2 methods to save:

```
private void saveBitmapIntoDevice(Bitmap bitmap, String imageName) {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(getOutputMediaFile(imageName));
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
        // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private File getOutputMediaFile(String imageName){

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null)
            + "/Android/data/"
            + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/Files");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    File mediaFile;
    String mImageName="IMG_" + imageName + ".png";
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
    return mediaFile;
}
```

How to get the data back:

```
File imgFile = getOutputMediaFile(imageName);

if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    image2.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Wear doesn't support `getExternalStorageDirectory()`; a `mkdirs()` call like yours also fails. I could speculate that, since storage on wearables tends to be quite limited, Google wants to constrain it to directories that will be automatically deleted when your app is uninstalled. With `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, there's no guarantee of this. But that's just speculation. :^)

Do you have a reason to use this legacy method? There are a lot of newer API calls which work fine on Wear. One example is  [`Context.getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)). If you truly need *external* storage, this is a "drop-in" replacement for your `getExternalStorageDirectory()` call.

But it's also worth noting that on wearables, the idea of *external* storage is on somewhat shaky ground. No current Wear device supports an SD card, and many don't even support the USB connection that would be required to mount them to a computer. As the documentation for `getExternalFilesDir` says,

> If a shared storage device is emulated (as determined by
>   isExternalStorageEmulated(File)), it's contents are backed by a
>   private user data partition, which means there is little benefit to
>   storing data here instead of the private directories returned by
>   getFilesDir(), etc.

I'd recommend reviewing [the Storage Options guide page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), considering what it is your app really needs in terms of storage, and using one of the newer, more focused calls.